# java class and "import com.google.gson.*" error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

in my java servlet project i used ajax and there i used gson jar file .without IDE Eclipse in kali linux as operating system .
i have put my `gson.jar` in WEB/lib/* and compile my program with `javac -d ... -cp  so the classpath is correct and when i use the same program in Eclipse it works well (here i entered the servlet-api.jar and WEB/lib/* to include all files)` but i faced this error

```
src/com/Servlets/AjaxController.java:9: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.*;
^
```

please guid me to the problem and thanks at first

Comment: Your classpath is incorrect

Comment: no iam sure is correct

Comment: Include it in your question please.

Comment: @Iman i have specified WE*/lib/* as classpath

Comment: If it is WE*/lib/* then it is not being considered as a correct classpath. Wildcards are only valid at the end of your path string.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using java version >= 1.6 cause as of this version wildcards (*) are being considered.

Second, Paths in your classpath must be seperated by : in unix systems instead of ; (which is in windows)

Thirdly, make sure you have used wildcard at the end of each path string.

Comment: my java version is   openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Debian-1.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Debian-1.1, mixed mode, sharing)  and when i use : instead of ; nothing changes and thanks sir

Comment: @userX Use : only in linux and change WE* to WEB and you will be fine 

Comment: @userX your welcome, please accept my answer if it helped.